# como calcular um resultado de um calculo em javascript?

Tags: javascript

tenho código em javascript que faz um calculo como mostra no código abaixo:

```
function calcular(){

    //1- 5S
    var valor1 = Number(document.getElementById('red1').value);
    var valor2 = Number(document.getElementById('red2').value);
    var valor3 = Number(document.getElementById('red3').value);
    var valor4 = Number(document.getElementById('red4').value);
    var valor5 = Number(document.getElementById('red5').value);

    var valor6 = Number(document.getElementById('yellow1').value);
    var valor7 = Number(document.getElementById('yellow2').value);
    var valor8 = Number(document.getElementById('yellow3').value);
    var valor9 = Number(document.getElementById('yellow4').value);
    var valor10 = Number(document.getElementById('yellow5').value);

    var valor11 = Number(document.getElementById('green1').value);
    var valor12 = Number(document.getElementById('green2').value);
    var valor13 = Number(document.getElementById('green3').value);
    var valor14 = Number(document.getElementById('green4').value);
    var valor15 = Number(document.getElementById('green5').value);

    document.getElementById('result1').value = Math.round((valor6 + valor7 + valor8 + valor9 + valor10 + valor11 + valor12 + valor13 + valor14 + valor15)/15 * 100)+"%";

    //2- 5S
    var valor16 = Number(document.getElementById('red6').value);
    var valor17 = Number(document.getElementById('red7').value);
    var valor18 = Number(document.getElementById('red8').value);
    var valor19 = Number(document.getElementById('red9').value);
    var valor20 = Number(document.getElementById('red10').value);
    var valor21 = Number(document.getElementById('red11').value);

    var valor22 = Number(document.getElementById('yellow6').value);
    var valor23 = Number(document.getElementById('yellow7').value);
    var valor24 = Number(document.getElementById('yellow8').value);
    var valor25 = Number(document.getElementById('yellow9').value);
    var valor26 = Number(document.getElementById('yellow10').value);
    var valor27 = Number(document.getElementById('yellow11').value);

    var valor28 = Number(document.getElementById('green6').value);
    var valor29 = Number(document.getElementById('green7').value);
    var valor30 = Number(document.getElementById('green8').value);
    var valor31 = Number(document.getElementById('green9').value);
    var valor32 = Number(document.getElementById('green10').value);
    var valor33 = Number(document.getElementById('green11').value);

    document.getElementById('result2').value =  Math.round((valor22 + valor23 + valor24 + valor25 + valor26 + valor27 + valor28 + valor29 + valor30 + valor31 + valor32 + valor33)/18 * 100)+"%";

    var valor34 = Number(document.getElementById('red12').value);
    var valor35 = Number(document.getElementById('red13').value);
    var valor36 = Number(document.getElementById('red14').value);
    var valor37 = Number(document.getElementById('red15').value);


    var valor38 = Number(document.getElementById('yellow12').value);
    var valor39 = Number(document.getElementById('yellow13').value);
    var valor40 = Number(document.getElementById('yellow14').value);
    var valor41 = Number(document.getElementById('yellow15').value);

    var valor42 = Number(document.getElementById('green12').value);
    var valor43 = Number(document.getElementById('green13').value);
    var valor44 = Number(document.getElementById('green14').value);
    var valor45 = Number(document.getElementById('green15').value);

    document.getElementById('result3').value =  Math.round((valor38 +  valor39 + valor40 + valor41 + valor42 + valor43 + valor44 + valor45)/12 * 100)+"%";

    var valor46 = Number(document.getElementById('red16').value);
    var valor47 = Number(document.getElementById('red17').value);
    var valor48 = Number(document.getElementById('red18').value);
    var valor49 = Number(document.getElementById('red19').value);


    var valor50 = Number(document.getElementById('yellow16').value);
    var valor51 = Number(document.getElementById('yellow17').value);
    var valor52 = Number(document.getElementById('yellow18').value);
    var valor53 = Number(document.getElementById('yellow19').value);

    var valor54 = Number(document.getElementById('green16').value);
    var valor55 = Number(document.getElementById('green17').value);
    var valor56 = Number(document.getElementById('green18').value);
    var valor57 = Number(document.getElementById('green19').value);

    document.getElementById('result4').value =  Math.round((valor50 +  valor51 + valor52 + valor53 + valor54 + valor55 + valor56 + valor57)/12 * 100)+"%";

    var valor58 = Number(document.getElementById('red20').value);
    var valor59 = Number(document.getElementById('red21').value);
    var valor60 = Number(document.getElementById('red22').value);
    var valor61 = Number(document.getElementById('red23').value);
    var valor62 = Number(document.getElementById('red24').value);
    var valor63 = Number(document.getElementById('red25').value);


    var valor64 = Number(document.getElementById('yellow20').value);
    var valor65 = Number(document.getElementById('yellow21').value);
    var valor66 = Number(document.getElementById('yellow22').value);
    var valor67 = Number(document.getElementById('yellow23').value);
    var valor68 = Number(document.getElementById('yellow24').value);
    var valor69 = Number(document.getElementById('yellow25').value);


    var valor70 = Number(document.getElementById('green20').value);
    var valor71 = Number(document.getElementById('green21').value);
    var valor72 = Number(document.getElementById('green22').value);
    var valor73 = Number(document.getElementById('green23').value);
    var valor74 = Number(document.getElementById('green24').value);
    var valor75 = Number(document.getElementById('green25').value);


    document.getElementById('result5').value =  Math.round((valor64 +  valor65 + valor66 + valor67 + valor68 + valor69 + valor70 + valor71 + valor72 + valor73 + valor74 + valor75)/18 * 100)+"%";

    var result1 = Number(document.getElementById('result1').value);
    var result2 = Number(document.getElementById('result2').value);
    var result3 = Number(document.getElementById('result3').value);
    var result4 = Number(document.getElementById('result4').value);
    var result5 = Number(document.getElementById('result5').value);

    document.getElementById('result').value = (result1 + result2 + result3 + result4 + result5)+"%";
}
```

As variáveis `result1`, `result2`... são o resultado do primeiro calculo.

Gostaria de somar o resultado desse calculo porém e imprime um valor `NaN` eu coloquei `Number.isNan(document.getElementById('result1').value);` e aparece o  valor `0`, mas não faz a soma dos valores.

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

código html tem mais quatro desse mesmo código, a ideia é somar o valor dos campos amarelos e verdes e dividir com o valor que esta no javascript vezes 100
para trazer uma porcentagem, isso irei fazer para cada  o resultado desse calculo vai para o campo com o id result1, e do outro  vai para o result2 
e assim por diante tendo esse resultado gostaria de soma-los por exemplo:

o usuário digita em um dos campos em amarelo 2 e um dos campos em verde 3 que da 5 dividirei pela quantidade de campo que nesse html é 15 e multiplico por 100 que arredondando 34% o que quero fazer é somar esses 34% pelos os resultados seguintes.

```
<tr>
    <td width="20%" height="50px">1- Existem materiais e/ou equipamentos que não estão sendo utilizados sobre as bancadas?</td>
    <td height="50px">
        <input type="text" name="red1" id="red1" onkeyup="calcular()" style="height: 100%; width: 96%; text-align:center" />
    </td>
    <td height="50px">
        <input type="text" name="yellow1" id="yellow1" onkeyup="calcular()" style="height: 100%; width: 96%; text-align:center" />
    </td>
    <td height="50px">
        <input type="text" name="green1" id="green1" onkeyup="calcular()" style="height: 100%; width: 96%; text-align:center" />
    </td>
    <td height="50px">
        <input type="text" name="na1" id="na1" style="height: 100%; width: 96%; text-align:center" />
    </td>
    <td colspan="2" height="50px">
        <input type="text" style="height: 100%; width: 99%;" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td width="20%" height="50px">2- Existem objetos desnecessários debaixo das bancadas (caixas de papelão, etc.)</td>
    <td height="50px">
        <input type="text" name="red2" id="red2" onkeyup="calcular()" style="height: 100%; width: 96%; text-align:center" />
    </td>
    <td height="50px">
        <input type="text" name="yellow2" id="yellow2" onkeyup="calcular()" style="height: 100%; width: 96%; text-align:center" />
    </td>
    <td height="50px">
        <input type="text" name="green2" id="green2" onkeyup="calcular()" style="height: 100%; width: 96%; text-align:center" />
    </td>
    <td height="50px">
        <input type="text" name="na2" id="na2" style="height: 100%; width: 96%; text-align:center" />
    </td>
    <td colspan="2" height="50px">
        <input type="text" style="height: 100%; width: 99%;" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td width="20%" height="50px">3- Os gabaritos não utilizados, ferramentas ou utensílios estão devidamente segregados e removidos da área de trabalho?</td>
    <td height="50px">
        <input type="text" name="red3" id="red3" onkeyup="calcular()" style="height: 100%; width: 96%; text-align:center" />
    </td>
    <td height="50px">
        <input type="text" name="yellow3" id="yellow3" onkeyup="calcular()" style="height: 100%; width: 96%; text-align:center" />
    </td>
    <td height="50px">
        <input type="text" name="green3" id="green3" onkeyup="calcular()" style="height: 100%; width: 96%; text-align:center" />
    </td>
    <td height="50px">
        <input type="text" name="na3" id="na3" style="height: 100%; width: 96%; text-align:center" />
    </td>
    <td colspan="2" height="50px">
        <input type="text" style="height: 100%; width: 99%;" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td width="20%" height="50px">4- Verificar se há fios de eletricidade, telefônicos espalhados pelo chão ou mesmo mal fixados nas paredes, proporcionando risco de acidentes ou demonstrando desorganização.</td>
    <td height="50px">
        <input type="text" name="red4" id="red4" onkeyup="calcular()" style="height: 100%; width: 96%; text-align:center" />
    </td>
    <td height="50px">
        <input type="text" name="yellow4" id="yellow4" onkeyup="calcular()" style="height: 100%; width: 96%; text-align:center" />
    </td>
    <td height="50px">
        <input type="text" name="green4" id="green4" onkeyup="calcular()" style="height: 100%; width: 96%; text-align:center" />
    </td>
    <td height="50px">
        <input type="text" name="na4" id="na4" style="height: 100%; width: 96%; text-align:center" />
    </td>
    <td colspan="2" height="50px">
        <input type="text" style="height: 100%; width: 99%;" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td width="20%" height="50px">5- Existem objetos pessoais no local de trabalho?</td>
    <td height="50px">
        <input type="text" name="red5" id="red5" onkeyup="calcular()" style="height: 100%; width: 96%; text-align:center" />
    </td>
    <td height="50px">
        <input type="text" name="yellow5" id="yellow5" onkeyup="calcular()" style="height: 100%; width: 96%; text-align:center" />
    </td>
    <td height="50px">
        <input type="text" name="green5" id="green5" onkeyup="calcular()" style="height: 100%; width: 96%; text-align:center" />
    </td>
    <td height="50px">
        <input type="text" name="na5" id="na5" style="height: 100%; width: 96%; text-align:center" />
    </td>
    <td colspan="2" height="50px">
        <input type="text" style="height: 100%; width: 99%;" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><b>Pontuação = Soma das notas divido pela quantidade de itens aplicáveis.</b></td>
    <td height='50px'>
        <input type="text" name="result1" id="result1" value="" style="width: 96%; height: 100%; text-align:center" />
    </td>
    <td colspan="5" height='50px'></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Há algum motivo para você não usar arrays ou laços?

Comment: Você pode editar a pergunta para inserir um HTML que contenha todos os elementos aos quais você se refere? Além disso, qual é a lógica do cálculo? É somar os elementos verdes e amarelos de algum agrupamento, mas não somar os vermelhos?

Comment: Esse código precisa de ser melhorado... qual é o padrão no HTML para saber quais as linhas que são somadas em qual input? reparei que algumas são de 4 em 4 outras 5 em 5. Depois de inputs há sempre uma `<tr>` com pontuação para os inputs anteriores?